# Сжать файл используя ZipArchive

Tags: c#, wpf, ziparchive

Как сжать уже имеющийся файл используя  класс ZipArchive, таким способом создается архим, но он пуст.

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"C:\123.txt", @"C:\12313.zip")
```

Или я не так понял смысл параметров? Как я понял первый параметр, задаем файл, который хотим сжать, второй параметр название архива и его путь где будет сжат файл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `ZipFile` запаковывает-распаковывает сразу целую папку.

Если нужно запаковать отдельный файл, используйте класс `ZipArchive`. Пример:

```
string path = @"C:\123.txt";
string filename = Path.GetFileName(path);

using (var dest = new FileStream(@"C:\12313.zip", FileMode.Create))
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(dest, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
using (var source = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
    ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry(filename);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[source.Length];
    source.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    using (var stream = entry.Open())
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я для этих целей использую библиотеку [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/)

Тогда архив из конкретной директории можно создать вот так:

```
 using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
  {
    zip.AddDirectory(@"MyDocuments\ProjectX", "ProjectX");
    zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G") ; 
    zip.Save(zipFileToCreate);
  }
```

Касательно кода из вопроса: Тебя не смущает, что метод называется `CreateFromDirectory`, а передаешь первым аргументом файл?

Comment: То есть он именно всё из каталога, а не файл отдельно